# How would I update the component that renders? Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React but I'm entirely self taught and using youtube videos so my learning is progressing but there are definitely gaps in my knowledge.

I've created a puzzle application using a drag and drop plugin that I want to change when the puzzle is completed using the 'dropped' method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { DragDropContainer, DropTarget } from 'react-drag-drop-container';

import VideoMov from '../../videos/vid.mov'; 
import VideoWebm from '../../videos/vid2.webm';

import "./puzzle.css";

export class Game extends Component {

    PuzzleContainer = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
    `;
        
    PuzzleBoard = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    `;
    
    PuzzleBoardTop = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 60px;        
    `;

    PuzzleBoardPieces = styled.div`
        height: ${ ({ height }) => height ? height + "px" : "210px" }; 
        width: ${ ({ width }) => width ? width + "px" : "85px" }; 
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        background-color: ${ ({ color }) => color ? '#' + color : "transparent" };
        margin-right: ${ ({ margin }) => margin ? "60px" : "0px" }
    `;

    PuzzleBoardBottom = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;    
    `;

    VideoWrapper = styled.div`
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
    `;
    
    PuzzleCounter = 0;
    Video = false;

    dropped = e => {
        // hide the dragged element once it is dropped over the correct puzzle drop item
        e.containerElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        e.target.classList.add('highlighted');
        this.PuzzleCounter++;

        if (this.PuzzleCounter === 3) {
            this.Video = true;
        }
    }


    render() {
        if (!this.Video) {
            return (
                <this.PuzzleContainer>
                    <this.PuzzleBoard>

                    <this.PuzzleBoardTop>
                        <DropTarget 
                            targetKey="piece-7314" 
                            dropData={ 
                            { name : 'left' }
                            }
                            onHit={ this.dropped }
                        >
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-board left" />
                        </DropTarget>
                        <DropTarget 
                            targetKey="piece-3167" 
                            dropData={ 
                            { name : 'middle' }
                            }
                            onHit={ this.dropped }
                        >
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-board middle" height={ 150 } width={ 90 } />
                        </DropTarget>
                        <DropTarget 
                            className="drop-container drop-container-right"
                            targetKey="piece-5149" 
                            dropData={ 
                            { name : 'right' }
                            }
                            onHit={ this.dropped }
                        >
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-board right" />
                        </DropTarget>
                    </this.PuzzleBoardTop>

                    <this.PuzzleBoardBottom>
                        <DragDropContainer targetKey="foo">
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece left" color="09203f" height={ 210 } width={ 170 } margin={ true } />
                        </DragDropContainer>
                        <DragDropContainer targetKey="foo">
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece middle" color="0a4ba6" height={ 210 } width={ 90 } margin={ true } />
                        </DragDropContainer>
                        <DragDropContainer 
                            targetKey="piece-7314"
                            dragData={
                            { label : 'left' }
                            }
                        >
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece left" color="118ab6" margin={ true } />
                        </DragDropContainer>
                        <DragDropContainer targetKey="foo">
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece right" color="173966" height={ 215 } width={ 70 } margin={ true } />
                        </DragDropContainer>
                        <DragDropContainer 
                            targetKey="piece-3167" 
                            dragData={
                            { label : 'middle' }
                        }
                        >
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece middle" color="052651" height={ 150 } width={ 90 } margin={ true } />
                        </DragDropContainer>
                        <DragDropContainer 
                            targetKey="piece-5149" 
                            dragData={
                            { label : 'right' }
                        }
                        >
                            <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece right" color="092c65" margin={ false } />
                        </DragDropContainer>
                    </this.PuzzleBoardBottom>

                    </this.PuzzleBoard>
                </this.PuzzleContainer>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <this.VideoWrapper>
                    <video width="600" height="100%" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                        <source src={ VideoMov } type='video/mp4; codecs="hvc1"' />
                        <source src={ VideoWebm } type="video/webm" />
                    </video>
                </this.VideoWrapper>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default Game
```

If I run through the application and complete the puzzle then nothing happens. Using the console I can see that Video updates to true, but the render function doesn't return anything new. Is there something I'm missing here?

Many thanks

---

### EDIT

I've taken the advice below and updated the video variable to be a state which works on the front end but the console now comes up with the following error:

*index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { DragDropContainer, DropTarget } from 'react-drag-drop-container';

import VideoMov from '../../videos/vid.mov'; 
import VideoWebm from '../../videos/vid2.webm';

import "./puzzle.css";

export class Game extends Component {

    state = {
        video: false,
    }

    PuzzleContainer = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
    `;
        
    PuzzleBoard = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    `;
    
    PuzzleBoardTop = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 60px;        
    `;

    PuzzleBoardPieces = styled.div`
        height: 50vw; 
        max-height: ${ ({ height }) => height ? height + "px" : "210px" };
        width: ${ ({ width }) => width ? width + "px" : "85px" }; 
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        background-color: ${ ({ color }) => color ? '#' + color : "transparent" };
        margin-right: ${ ({ margin }) => margin ? "60px" : "0px" }
    `;

    PuzzleBoardBottom = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;    
    `;

    VideoWrapper = styled.div`
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        video {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    `;
    
    PuzzleCounter = 0;

    dropped = e => {
        e.containerElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        e.target.classList.add('highlighted');
        this.PuzzleCounter++;

        if (this.PuzzleCounter === 3) {
            // this.props.completeFunction('complete');
            this.setState({
                video :  true
            });
        }
    }

    PuzzleGame = (
            <this.PuzzleBoard>

                <this.PuzzleBoardTop>
                    <DropTarget 
                        targetKey="piece-7314" 
                        dropData={ 
                            { name : 'left' }
                        }
                        onHit={ this.dropped }
                    >
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-board left" />
                    </DropTarget>
                    <DropTarget 
                        targetKey="piece-3167" 
                        dropData={ 
                            { name : 'middle' }
                        }
                        onHit={ this.dropped }
                    >
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-board middle" height={ 150 } width={ 90 } />
                    </DropTarget>
                    <DropTarget 
                        className="drop-container drop-container-right"
                        targetKey="piece-5149" 
                        dropData={ 
                            { name : 'right' }
                        }
                        onHit={ this.dropped }
                    >
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-board right" />
                    </DropTarget>
                </this.PuzzleBoardTop>

                <this.PuzzleBoardBottom>
                    <DragDropContainer targetKey="foo">
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece left" color="09203f" height={ 210 } width={ 170 } margin={ true } />
                    </DragDropContainer>
                    <DragDropContainer targetKey="foo">
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece middle" color="0a4ba6" height={ 210 } width={ 90 } margin={ true } />
                    </DragDropContainer>
                    <DragDropContainer 
                        targetKey="piece-7314"
                        dragData={
                            { label : 'left' }
                        }
                    >
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece left" color="118ab6" margin={ true } />
                    </DragDropContainer>
                    <DragDropContainer targetKey="foo">
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece right" color="173966" height={ 215 } width={ 70 } margin={ true } />
                    </DragDropContainer>
                    <DragDropContainer 
                        targetKey="piece-3167" 
                        dragData={
                            { label : 'middle' }
                        }
                    >
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece middle" color="052651" height={ 150 } width={ 90 } margin={ true } />
                    </DragDropContainer>
                    <DragDropContainer 
                        targetKey="piece-5149" 
                        dragData={
                            { label : 'right' }
                        }
                    >
                        <this.PuzzleBoardPieces className="puzzle-piece right" color="092c65" margin={ false } />
                    </DragDropContainer>
                </this.PuzzleBoardBottom>

            </this.PuzzleBoard>
    );

    VideoContainer = (
        <this.VideoWrapper>
            <video autoPlay muted playsInline>
                <source src={ VideoMov } type='video/mp4; codecs="hvc1"' />
                <source src={ VideoWebm } type="video/webm" />
            </video>
        </this.VideoWrapper>
    );

    render() {

        const { video } = this.state;
        return (
            <this.PuzzleContainer>
                { !video ? this.PuzzleGame : this.VideoContainer }
            </this.PuzzleContainer>
        );

    }
}

export default Game
```

Comment: I think it would work if you turned the video variable into state. Whenever state is updated it reloads the component with the new state. [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thanks @JarneKompier I changed video to state but which works but I now get the following error:

index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.